# PHP - Allowing only one admin registration for page

Tags: php, html, database

I'm trying to create a form for admin registration. The code works correctly but more than one admin can register for this page. How can I make it so that only one admin can register?

```html
<html >
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
print ("<form action='admin.php' method='post'>
    <p>Name
        <input type='text' name='firstname'  />
    </p>
    <p>Surname
        <input type='text' name='lastname' />
    </p>
    <p>Username
        <input type='text' name='username' />
    </p>
    <p>Password
        <input type='password' name='password' />
        </p>
        <p>Email <input type='text' name='email'/>  </p>
      

      
    
  <input type='submit'  value='Register'/>  
</form>

        ");



if( !($database=mysql_connect("localhost","root",""))||!(mysql_select_db("st_login",$database))  )
   print("Could not connect");

if(isset($_POST['firstname'] )&&isset($_POST['lastname'])&&isset($_POST['username'])&&isset($_POST['password'])
  /*&&isset($_POST['notat'])&&isset($_POST['lendet'])*/&&isset($_POST['email'])){
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=md5($_POST['password']);
$email=$_POST['email'];
/*
$notat=$_POST['notat'];
$lendet=$_POST['lendet'];
*/

$query = "INSERT INTO  login (firstname, lastname, username,password,email,admin) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname',
 '$username','$password','$email',1)";
}
if ( !empty($firstname)&&!empty($lastname)&&!empty($username) &&!empty($password)&&!empty($email))
{
  if(!($result=mysql_query($query,$database)))
{
    print("Could not execute query");
    die (mysql_error());//ose error
}
echo "YOU HAVE BEEN REGISTERED SUCCESSFULLY!You are the admin of this page";

}
else echo 'Fill in all the blank fields';
mysql_close($database);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my database [image: database]

Comment: Well, you're not checking to see if there are any admins in the db before adding one. Btw... Don't use deprecated `mysql_*` functions and your query is wide open for SQL injections.

Comment: Check if a record is there with `admin = 1` or not. Use `SELECT` statement for that.

Comment: Btw. Why are you printing the form through PHP instead of having it in the HTML-markup?

Comment: I forgot... using `md5()` for password hashing is really insecure. You should use something like sha256 with a proper salt (don't roll your own. Use `password_hash()` if you're on PHP 5.5+ or use some other "official" package if you're not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a check when inputting user data to the form. Check whether there are any rows where the field admin is set to 1 (or whatever you use)
Sample code for that

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT firstname FROM mytable WHERE admin=1");
if(mysql_num_rows($result)== 0) {
     //check if the post variables are set and input the values to the table
} else {
     // Admin already exist      
}
```

---

As mentioned in comments, you should stop using `mysql_`, and use `mysqli_` or PDO with **prepared statements** instead, an example is given below. Keep in mind that you cannot mix APIs, so your entire code will have to be converted from one to the other.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "database");

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT firstname FROM mytable WHERE admin=1");
if ($result->num_rows == 0) 
     //check if the post variables are set and input the values to the table
} else {
     // Admin already exist      
}
```

Reference

- [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
- [Choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)
- [`$mysqli->prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) (for prepared statements)

Comment: You really shouldn't use deprecated functions like `mysql_*`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks for pointing that out. Please use mysqli

Comment: Your can't mix APIs, so if OP is using `mysql_`, he can't use something with `mysqli_` - it's one or the other. Secondly, the query in `mysqli_query` needs two parameters, the first one being the connection.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, can you please update my answer with that, or post a new one.